# How to use subList()

Tags: java

I have a JSF page which displays list of Glassfish log files. I use lazy loading for pagination. I keep the list of the log files names into Java `List`.

```
private List<directoryListObj> dataList = new ArrayList<>();

dataList = dataList.subList(firstRow, lastRow);
```

And here is the problem. For example I have 35 files into the directory. When I do this

```
dataList = dataList.subList(5, 15);
```

It works fine. But when I do this:

```
dataList = dataList.subList(30, 38);
```

I get error wrong index because I want to get index outside of the List. How I can for example return List elements from 30 to 35? I want if I want to get index from 30 to 40 but if there only 35 indexes to get only 5.

Comment: `dataList = dataList.subList(30, 38 > dataList.size() ? dataList.size() : 38);`

Comment: Or `dataList.subList(30, Math.min(38, dataList.size())`

Comment: @pb2q looks like you've lost the chance for an answer.

Comment: If you look at the [APIdoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29) you'll notice that it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException - endpoint index value out of range (fromIndex < 0 || toIndex > size)`. So look at the APIdoc for such hints in the future.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Using `subList(30, 38);` will fail because max index 38 is not available in list, so its not possible.

Only way may be before asking for the sublist, you explicitly determine the max index using list size() method.

for example, check size, which returns 35, so call `sublist(30, size());`

OR

**COPIED FROM pb2q comment**

```
dataList = dataList.subList(30, 38 > dataList.size() ? dataList.size() : 38);
```

Comment: That would also fail if the list has less than 30 items.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK: Yes you are correct, but assumption was list has more than 30 items.

Comment: I prefer `dataList = dataList.subList(30, Math.min(38, dataList.size()));`

Answer (score 53):

I've implemented and tested this one; it should cover most bases:

```
public static <T> List<T> safeSubList(List<T> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (fromIndex >= size || toIndex <= 0 || fromIndex >= toIndex) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    fromIndex = Math.max(0, fromIndex);
    toIndex = Math.min(size, toIndex);

    return list.subList(fromIndex, toIndex);
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the only one who bothered to test their code.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. Breaking this out into a method makes more sense than trying to wrap up the logic in ternary operators, it just gets too hard to read that way.

Answer (score 43):

To get the last element, simply use the size of the list as the second parameter. So for example, if you have 35 files, and you want the last five, you would do:

```
dataList.subList(30, 35);
```

A guaranteed safe way to do this is:

```
dataList.subList(Math.max(0, first), Math.min(dataList.size(), last) );
```

Comment: That would also fail if 'first' is greater than the list size.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK: or if `last` is negative!

Comment: Also will fail if `first >= last`

Answer (score 14):

You could use streams in Java 8. To always get 10 entries at the most, you could do:

```
dataList.stream().skip(5).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
dataList.stream().skip(30).limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 4):

Although it may be too late, I suggest using stream in Java 8 to avoid handling the out of boundry exception manually.

this code

```
dataList = dataList.stream().skip(30).limit(8).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

works same as

```
dataList = dataList.subList(30, 38);
```

and in case of out of index error, dataList will be empty list instead of throwing any exception.

Comment: How is that different to my answer above? :D

Answer (score 0):

Better to use Skip and limit because subList can cause index out of bound expection

Answer (score -1):

For kotlin, you could use:
`myList.subList(min, max.coerceAtMost(myList.size)`

Or in terms of the question above: `myList.subList(30, 38.coerceAtMost(myList.size)`