# Java or Kotlin - create as much of sublist as possible

Tags: java, list, kotlin

In Java or Kotlin, how can I create as much of a sublist as possible? If the range is greater than the size of the list, it should just ignore parts of the range that are out of bounds.

I currently have (Kotlin):

```
val list: List = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.subList(0, 3) // -> [1, 2, 3]
list.subList(0, 5) // -> IndexOutOfBoundsException
list.subList(0, 200) // -> IndexOutOfBoundsException
list.clear()
list.subList(0, 3) // -> IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

I would like (Kotlin):

```
val list: List = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.subList(0, 3) // -> [1, 2, 3]
list.subList(0, 5) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.subList(0, 200) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.clear()
list.subList(0, 3) // -> []
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099721/how-to-use-sublist

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could write an extension on `List<T>` to do this logic for you:

```
fun <T> List<T>.safeSubList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): List<T> =
    this.subList(fromIndex, toIndex.coerceAtMost(this.size))
```

This uses `coerceAtMost` to limit the highest value.

And to call it:

```
val list = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
println(list.safeSubList(0, 200)) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or as @gidds suggests, we could make this even safer:

```
fun <T> List<T>.safeSubList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): List<T> = 
    this.subList(fromIndex.coerceAtLeast(0), toIndex.coerceAtMost(this.size))
```

This version guards against specifying numbers out of range on both ends. If you pass in numbers such that from > to, it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` from `subList`.

Comment: That would be my approach, too.  You could make it even safer by limiting the fromValue, too; and by restricting them to be >= 0 as well as <= `size`; and possibly by ensuring `fromIndex` <= `toIndex` as well.  (Though arguably that might be _too_ safe…)

Answer (score 12):

In Kotlin you can do

```kotlin
val list = mutableListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
list.take(3) // -> [1, 2, 3]
list.take(5) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.take(200) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.clear()
list.take(3) // -> []
```

You can check the implementation of `take` if you'd like.

Answer (score 2):

Arraylist is implemented over array. so you can not be able to get sublist than the real amount.

```
arrayListOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

it means, You can only get the range between 0 - 4

---

You can try this to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
int maxRange = yourGivenMaxRange;

    if(maxRange > list.size()){
        maxRange = list.size();
    }

list.subList(0, maxRange) // -> [1, 2, 3]
list.subList(0, maxRange) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.subList(0, maxRange) // -> [1, 2, 3, 4]
list.clear()
list.subList(0, maxRange) // -> []
```

Comment: OP says he knows this, but he needs a different behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It would be work.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min

fun <T> List<T>.safeSubList(fromIndex: Int, toIndex: Int): List<T> {
    if (fromIndex > toIndex) return emptyList()
    return subList(max(min(fromIndex.coerceAtLeast(0), size), 0), max(min(toIndex.coerceAtMost(size), size), 0))
}
```

example)

```kotlin
val a = (1..10).toList()
println(a.safeSubList(9, 10))
println(a.safeSubList(-1, -2))
println(a.safeSubList(1, 0))
println(a.safeSubList(-9, 4))
println(a.safeSubList(4, 5))
println(a.safeSubList(9, 15))
```

result)

```
[10]
[]
[]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5]
[10]
```