# Optimize FOR loop for adding array elements to set

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, set

I have an array `Ar` of size N(`Ar[N]`). I have to divide the `Ar[N]` into sub arrays of size `K` and then add them to a Set S.
For example if `Ar[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}` and `K = 3`
then,
Sub arrays will be `{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{3,4,5}`
Now I have to add these sub arrays to the Set and continue my computations.

Here is my code :

```
int max = 0;
for(int j=0;j<=N-k;j++){
            Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
            for(int l=j;l<j+K;l++){
                set.add(Ar[l]);
            }
if(set.size >= max) max = set.size;
        }
System.out.println(max);
```

Is there any way that I can get rid of the nested for loop as in worst case N can be 1000000.
**NOTE** : The set should only contain unique values.
Hope I am clear.

Comment: There isn't really a way to make this more efficient given the problem as you've stated it.  Anything you do is going to need to end up doing O(NK) work.

Comment: Can you give the full problem statement - cause at this level I agree with Louis

Comment: Can you show how you *use* the set of sub arrays? Perhaps it's possible to change the program so it's not necessary to construct this set entirely

Comment: Hi @Joni, I calculate the max size of the set. I added it to my code. please have a look.

Comment: But in our code I see a set of Integer not a set of array of Integer. What did I miss?

Comment: Subham - You seem to be confused. The way you have explained your question, [the answer by saka1029](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63322720/10819573) which he has deleted and therefore is visible to only ones who have 10k+ reputation points, was correct. And as @Joni has mentioned, it's not necessary to construct this set entirely. If all you want is the total number of elements in all the sub-arrays, it will be `(N - K + 1) * K`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maintain a window of `i-k-1` to `i` of set when traversing the array. You can use `HashMap` to count the frequency of value and remove it when the frequency is zero.  And update max value of set then you will get max set size of each subarray's set.

```
int[] arr = {1,2,1,4,1};
int k = 3;
int max = 0;
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  set.add(arr[i]);
  map.merge(arr[i], 1, Integer::sum);
  if(i >= k) {
    map.merge(arr[i-k], -1, Integer::sum);
    if(map.get(arr[i-k]) == 0) {
      set.remove(arr[i-k]);
    }
  }
  if(set.size() >= max) {
    max = set.size();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If actual task is to define the maximum size of a subset after dividing into K elements, it can be implemented this way:

```
public static long findMaxSize(int[] arr, int k) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, arr.length - k)
                    .mapToLong(i -> 
                        Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, i + k))
                              .distinct().count())
                    .max().getAsLong();
}
```

Also, splitting of the input array by K elements into *subsets* may be implemented this way:

```
public static Set<Set<Integer>> splitIntoSubsetsByK(int[] arr, int k) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, arr.length - k)
                    .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, i + k))
                        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
    }
```

Test and output:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 2, 2, 1};
int k = 3;

Set<Set<Integer>> result = splitIntoSubsetsByK(arr, k);
result.forEach(System.out::println);

System.out.println(findMaxSize(arr, k));

[1, 2]
[2]
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution. Try to use "subList()" described in:  [How to use subList()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099721/how-to-use-sublist)

See example below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int startNumber = 1;
    int endNumber = 5;
    List<Integer> mainList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++) {
        mainList.add(i);
    }

    // See mainList:
    System.out.println(mainList); // output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    int sizeOfEachSubList = 3;
    int loopStopPoint = mainList.size() - sizeOfEachSubList;
    List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= loopStopPoint; i++) {
        List<Integer> subList = mainList.subList(i, sizeOfEachSubList + i);
        listOfLists.add(subList);
    }

    //See all lists:
    System.out.println(listOfLists); // output: [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
}
```